# RouteAttribute's Order is completely ignored on IRouteConstraint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

We have an `IRouteConstraint` that is getting checked much more than it should. Upon further testing, it looks like that `Order` on `[Route]` gets ignored by route constraints.

For example, if I have the following constraint:

```
public class TestConstraint : IRouteConstraint {
    public bool Match(
        HttpContextBase httpContext,
        Route route,
        string parameterName,
        RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection
    ) {
        Debug.WriteLine("TestConstraint");
        return true;
    }
}
```

And wire it up:

```
constraintResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("testConstraint", typeof(TestConstraint));
```

And have the following routes:

```
public partial class HomeController {
    [Route("test/0", Order = 1)]
    public ActionResult Test0() {
        return Content("Test0");
    }

    [Route("{someParam}/{test:testConstraint}", Order = 10)]
    public ActionResult Test1() {
        return Content("Test1");
    }
}
```

And then make a request for `http://localhost/test/0`, it will return the proper content (`Test0`), but `TestContraint.Match()` is still executed.

I would think that route constraints are only executed once the route is encountered in the `RouteTable`, but it seems to run it on *every* request that can match the `[Route]` pattern.

If it makes a difference, we are on ASP.NET MVC v5.2.4.

Comment: _it will return the proper content (Test1)_ - did you mean `"Test0"`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, thanks for pointing out. Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET MVC pipeline, the stage of routing and the stage of selection of invoked controller action are separated. On routing stage you can't just select the first matching action and stop further lookup. Found action (strictly speaking method) could be filtered on later stage. For example it may not satisfy applied action selectors (e.g. `NonAction` attribute).

That's why basic action selection algorithm is the following:

1. Pass Request URL through configured routes and select all matching actions.
2. Pass all matching actions through action selectors, filter out non matching.
3. Order candidate actions by routing order.

Now there are following options:

1. No matching actions found. Request result to 404 error.
2. Multiple matching actions share the same highest order. Exception is thrown ("The current request is ambiguous between the following action methods ...").
3. Exactly one matching action have highest order (or one action matches at all). The action is selected and executed.

If you are interested in correspondig ASP.NET MVC source code, here are some references:

`IRouteConstraint.Match()` is invoked by `ProcessConstraint()` method in `System.Web.Routing.Route`. The nearest method in call stack, which operates on route collection level, is `GetRouteData()` method in `System.Web.Mvc.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute` class:

[image]

Here is its [source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Web.Mvc/Routing/RouteCollectionRoute.cs#L31):

```
public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    List<RouteData> matches = new List<RouteData>();
    foreach (RouteBase route in _subRoutes)
    {
        var match = route.GetRouteData(httpContext);
        if (match != null)
        {
            matches.Add(match);
        }
    }

    return CreateDirectRouteMatch(this, matches);
}
```

As you see, the loop does not break when matching route is found.

The code that applies action selectors, performs ordering and chooses action candidate resides in `DirectRouteCandidate.SelectBestCandidate()` ([source code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Web.Mvc/Routing/DirectRouteCandidate.cs#L81)):

```
public static DirectRouteCandidate SelectBestCandidate(List<DirectRouteCandidate> candidates, ControllerContext controllerContext)
{
    Debug.Assert(controllerContext != null);
    Debug.Assert(candidates != null);

    // These filters will allow actions to opt-out of execution via the provided public extensibility points.
    List<DirectRouteCandidate> filteredByActionName = ApplyActionNameFilters(candidates, controllerContext);
    List<DirectRouteCandidate> applicableCandidates = ApplyActionSelectors(filteredByActionName, controllerContext);

    // At this point all of the remaining actions are applicable - now we're just trying to find the
    // most specific match.
    //
    // Order is first, because it's the 'override' to our algorithm
    List<DirectRouteCandidate> filteredByOrder = FilterByOrder(applicableCandidates);
    List<DirectRouteCandidate> filteredByPrecedence = FilterByPrecedence(filteredByOrder);

    if (filteredByPrecedence.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else if (filteredByPrecedence.Count == 1)
    {
        return filteredByPrecedence[0];
    }
    else
    {
        throw CreateAmbiguiousMatchException(candidates);
    }
}
```

Comment: so is this a bug or by design, doesn't seem to make sense to me, so to me its a huge bug am i missing something